# Fit dataframe into linear regression sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am making a project for a class, and i am trying to predict nfl socre games using linear regression and predict functions from sklearn, my problem comes when i want to fit the training data into de fit function, here is my code:

```
onehotdata_x1 = pd.get_dummies(goal_model_data,columns=['team','opponent'])

# Crea el object de regression linear
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(onehotdata_x1[['home','team','opponent']], onehotdata_x1['goals'])
```

This is the structure of dataframe(goal_model_data):

```
team opponent  goals  home
 NE       KC     27     1
BUF      NYJ     21     1
CHI      ATL     17     1
CIN      BAL      0     1
CLE      PIT     18     1
DET      ARI     35     1
HOU      JAX      7     1
TEN      OAK     16     1
```

and this is the error that i get when i run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predictnflgames.py", line 76, in <module>
    regr.fit(onehotdata_x1[['home','team','opponent']], onehotdata_x1['goals'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2133, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2177, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1269, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "['team' 'opponent'] not in index"
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `onehotdata_x1.head()`

Comment: You are trying to access columns that do not exist after using pd. get_dummies. see my answer for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that after `pd.get_dummies` there are no `team` and `opponent` columns.

I use this data in txt format for my example: https://ufile.io/e2vtv (same as yours).

---

**Try this and see:**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

goal_model_data = pd.read_table('goal_model_data.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

onehotdata_x1 = pd.get_dummies(goal_model_data,columns=['team','opponent'])

regr = LinearRegression()

#see the columns in onehotdata_x1
onehotdata_x1.columns

#see the data (only 2 rows of the data for the example)
onehotdata_x1.head(2)
```

---

**Results:**

```
Index([u'goals', u'home', u'team_BUF', u'team_CHI', u'team_CIN', u'team_CLE',
       u'team_DET', u'team_HOU', u'team_NE', u'team_TEN', u'opponent_ARI',
       u'opponent_ATL', u'opponent_BAL', u'opponent_JAX', u'opponent_KC',
       u'opponent_NYJ', u'opponent_OAK', u'opponent_PIT'],
       dtype='object')
```

---

```
goals  home  team_BUF  team_CHI  team_CIN  team_CLE  team_DET  team_HOU  \
0     27     1         0         0         0         0         0         0
1     21     1         1         0         0         0         0         0

team_NE  team_TEN  opponent_ARI  opponent_ATL  opponent_BAL  opponent_JAX  \
0        1         0             0             0             0             0
1        0         0             0             0             0             0

opponent_KC  opponent_NYJ  opponent_OAK  opponent_PIT
0            1             0             0             0
1            0             1             0             0
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Based on the original code, you might want to do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pd.read_table('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

onehotdata = pd.get_dummies(data,columns=['team','opponent'])

regr = LinearRegression()

#in x get all columns except goals column
x = onehotdata.loc[:, onehotdata.columns != 'goals']

#use goals column as target variable
y= onehotdata['goals']

regr.fit(x,y)
regr.predict(x)
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually `pd.get_dummies()` will drop only the `team` and `opponent` columns. `goals` and `home` will remain. You can also see that the `KeyError` is returned only for `team` and `opponent`.

Comment: yes this is what i show in my example. after `pd.get_dummies`  there is no `team` and `opponent` column. cheers

Comment: You should correct your first sentence, where you say otherwise.

Comment: It's not just a silly mistake. It represents something bigger. An error of thinking that makes you who you are. (Just kidding, took a look at your profile where you had that written :) )

Comment: so how could i use the dummies created?

Answer (score -1):

When you use `pd.get_dummies(goal_model_data,columns=['team','opponent'])` the `team` and `opponent` column will be dropped from your dataframe and `onehotdata_x1` won't contain these two columns.

Then, when you do `onehotdata_x1[['home','team','opponent']]` you get a `KeyError` simply because `team` and `opponent` do not exist as columns in the `onehotdata_x1` dataframe.

Using a toy dataframe, here's what happens:

[image: img]

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't be using the `team` and `opponent` columns anyway as independent variables when fitting with linear regression because they are categorical and linear regression works only with numbers under the hood. You should rather use the dummy variables created.

Comment: but how can i use the dummy variables created?

Comment: @xtrios you should print `onehotdata_x1` to understand what's happening here. You'll see a couple of new columns created in comparison with the original `goal_model_data` dataframe. These new columns are the dummy variables. You want to select those, along with the `home` variable as features, and use the `goals` column as target.